# Header ObservableScrollView with the effect of elastic

Tags: android, scrollview, toolbar

I am using the [ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and would like to put an elastic effect on the toolbar (with the ImageView). In the case when pull down the ObservableScrollView (ie'm already in the scroll top limit) would stretch the toolbar and then return to its original size. An example of the effect that would [link](http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/) the toolbar received.

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat library from Facebook developers, [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) that simulates spring physics and generates values that you can use to create springy, elastic animations. They have implemented a [springy scroll view example](https://github.com/facebook/rebound/blob/master/rebound-android-playground/src/main/java/com/facebook/rebound/playground/examples/SpringScrollViewExample.java), which is probably what you are looking for.
You can download the whole project and run "rebound-android-playground" to see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, very good this lib, but I'm having trouble making the ObservableScrollView the header have the effect of elastic, as with the iOS or conform the mentioned link. In git examples exist some effects but nothing to what I'm trying to employ.